# UITextView set detection is phone number not working in IOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, uitextviewdelegate

I have UITextView and I set detection is phone number when I long press phone number I need show popup (image below) with ios 8 it's work but ios 9 it's not working?
[image]

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6PyWQ7V-YGsTkM4dno2c2ZFTGc/view?usp=sharing download the sample

Comment: @MuhammadAdnan Thanks for answers, I tested your code on my device it's work but it's not resolved my problem for me, maybe the problem in my logic code.